# ¿Como hacer una lista mutable en java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quisiera saber si se puede hacer una lista mutable en java, y como se pudiera hacer. Gracias

Comment: List lista = new ArrayList(), así tiene una lista mutable

Answer (score 0):

En general, salvo que indiquen lo contrario, las colecciones de Java son mutables.

Por ej [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) tiene los métodos [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) y [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) para agregar y quitar elementos respectivamente.